# AWT Image Resize and Preserve EXIF Data

Tags: java, awt, exif, image-resizing

My program resizes images with SWT (Graphics2D).  It works by reading a file, performing the resize, and then writing out to another file.  But, I need to preserve the EXIF data, so this doesn't work.  Is there a way to keep the EXIF data, or else read the EXIF data from the original image and write to the new one?  I'm currently using [Drew Noaks' Metadata Extractor](http://www.drewnoakes.com/drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) for extracting the data for my own purposes.

Comment: Figured it out, here's the code I used: http://pastebin.com/x1Sh7bZR The important parts are `resizeImage` and `convertToSWT`.

Comment: My solution using a combination of ImageIO, Imgscalr and Apache commons-imaging is pasted on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972357/manipulate-an-image-without-deleting-its-exif-data

Comment: @MatthewGreen this question is actually significantly older, and has an answer.