# Lossless JPG crop without losing EXIF, on Android

Tags: java, android, jpeg, exif, lossless

I implement a crop feature on an Android app for JPG files, with very strict requirements:

- The EXIF must be kept.
- The crop must be [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Lossless_editing) (*as a consequence the crop can only be done at certain places, that's OK*).
- App size is very strict, so any needed library should be like 300 KB or less, ideally no library.

The [Manipulate an image without deleting its EXIF data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972357/manipulate-an-image-without-deleting-its-exif-data) question is a bit similar but unfortunately the first solution uses `javax.imageio.ImageIO` which is not available on Android, and the second solution uses a library which is too big, 690 KB.

Is there any way to do that, preferably with the standard Android classes?

Comment: I have not tried but are their any performance issues on extracting the exif data from image, converting it to cropped bitmap and compressing it back by adding the extracted exif data?

Comment: @MohammedAtif: I am unfortunately not a JPG specialist, but I believe that lossless JPG cropping can be done without decompression/recompression, which would be better in terms of memory and CPU usage. But answers that do not use this technique are still OK so feel free to post :-)

Comment: Perhaps an [`lljtran` port for Java](https://github.com/drogatkin/mediautil) would work? Don't know the library size, but you could probably rip out just the parts you need.

Comment: @haraldK: Wonderful find! It sure beats re-implementing the JPG algorithms myself. Feel free to post an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

For this I've been using [LLCrop](https://github.com/k3b/LosslessJpgCrop/issues) open source.
Maybe you can see how they did, or just use it, it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you are going to find such a thing off-the-shelf. You would be restricting yourself to crops along MCU boundaries. The MCU size depends upon the sampling rates of the various components.

This is not a trivial task.

Comment: Yes exactly, crop will be done along MCU boundaries only, you understood the question correctly.