# Write JPEG Exif DateTimeOriginal and TimeZoneOffset from scratch using Apache Commons Imaging

Tags: java, exif, apache-commons-imaging

I have a JPEG file from which I have removed *all* metadata. Using Java with [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) I want to add custom metadata to the JPEG from scratch. Using `ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossy(…)` I have managed to update the following Exif tags because they are in IFD0:

- `ImageDescription` (`0x010E`)
- `Artist` (`0x013B`)
- `Copyright` (`0x8298`)

I get IFD0 using `getOrCreateRootDirectory()`; using `getOrCreateExifDirectory()` doesn't seem to work if I'm creating metadata from scratch:

```java
TiffOutputSet tiffOutputSet = new TiffOutputSet();
TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = tiffOutputSet.getOrCreateRootDirectory();
…
TagInfoAscii tagImageDescription = new TagInfoAscii("ImageDescription", 0x010E, -1, TiffDirectoryType.EXIF_DIRECTORY_IFD0);
…
exifDirectory.add(tagImageDescription, "foo bar")
…
new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossy(byteSource, outputStream, tiffOutputSet);
```

This is working but the last piece of (this section of the) puzzle is to add image creation timestamp information. This would be these Exif tags:

- `DateTimeOriginal` (`0x9003`)
- `SubSecTimeOriginal` (`0x9291`)
- `TimeZoneOffset` (`0x882a`)

However these Exif tags don't seem to be in some other Exif directory. (Going from [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor), it would seem to be the "sub IDF" directory). But how do I get this other Exif SubIFD directory in Apache Commons Imaging so that I can add these tags? (Remember that I am writing all this metadata from scratch, not modifying metadata.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57757312) I discovered that what I want is the method `TiffOutputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory()`. Apparently Apache Commons Imaging uses its own naming convention:

- IFD0: Apache Commons Imaging calls this the "root directory"
- SubIFD: Apache Commons Imaging calls this the "Exif directory"

It thus appears I can do this:

```java
TiffOutputSet tiffOutputSet = new TiffOutputSet();
TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = tiffOutputSet.getOrCreateRootDirectory();
TiffOutputDirectory subExifDirectory = tiffOutputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
…
TagInfoAscii tagImageDescription = new TagInfoAscii("ImageDescription", 0x010E, -1, TiffDirectoryType.EXIF_DIRECTORY_IFD0);
…
exifDirectory.add(tagImageDescription, "foo bar")
subExifDirectory.add(EXIF_TAG_DATE_TIME_ORIGINAL, dateString); //TODO format appropriately
…
new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossy(byteSource, outputStream, tiffOutputSet);
```