# Copy image with Exif metadata

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-tika

I have an image I want to resize. I'm using `BufferedImage` and the image has the dimensions I wanted.
The only problem is that my image is rotated.

I did some investigation and turned out exif data is lost when new image is created.

I have found the following answer already ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36675321/2290763)), unfortunately the solution suggested in the link does not work - freshly copied image does not have exif metadata, it is rotated.

How can I copy an image with its metadata using either pure Java or eg. Apache Commons/Tika parsers?

Comment: *"unfortunately it does not work."* - does not work as in the exif metadata not written, image corrupted, or you encountered errors? how your code looked like?

Comment: @BagusTesa I've added additional description. What I mean there is that new image does not have exif metadata regarding orientation.